# When counting information from an array the result is -1 from the actual result

Tags: javascript, loops

I'm grabbing a spreadsheet from an online report the file is a CSV file  I format so is usable by gscript.

So I'm counting everything that's a value over 0 in a loop and using an array. but when displaying the information in one value less...so let's say there are 7 values on the sheet the logger displays 6...I'm super new on this so I'll appreciate any help.

The commission variable is the one with the issue

```
function start()
{
    var startDate = new Date();
    var endDate = new Date();   

    var sMonth = startDate.getMonth()+1; //start day variables
    var sDay = startDate.getDate()-3;
    var sYear = startDate.getFullYear();

    startDate = sMonth+"-"+sDay+"-"+sYear; //concatenate date
    endDate = startDate;

    var csvUrl = "http://publisherpro.flexoffers.com/Report/Public?gui=9ce2029a-e14c-4548-a1af-0f0e2e8894c8&d1=" +startDate+"&d2="+endDate+ "&t=A&o=CSV"

    Logger.log(csvUrl);

    var csvContent = UrlFetchApp.fetch(csvUrl).getContentText(); // 
    Just formating the file to be useable within Google Scripts
    var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(csvContent); // Same as above //Returns a tabular 2D array representation of a CSV string.

    var counter = new Array;
    var commision = 0;
    for (var c = 2; c < csvData.length; c++) {

      if (csvData[c][21] > 0) 
      {
        commision++
      }
      }
      Logger.log(commision)
}
```

Comment: You're starting from index `2`, use `var c = 0` instead of `var c= 2` in your `for loop`

Comment: Or start at 1 if you want to skip the header which is at 0. JS Arrays are 0 based

Comment: _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers._

Comment: Thank you booth for taking the time to answer this! It worked!!